# How do I find/replace strange characters in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

When I open a sql dump file in notepad++ and view it with utf8 encoding, (as that was it was encoded as) I see these strange block characters such as A0 or 93 that I can't find/replace. My friend using emacs can see these characters as /204 or /205, and so on, and was able to find/replace on his editor.

How do I make it so I can do the same using notepad++? There are several characters he missed and I'm stuck hand fixing them one by one. It's important to get rid of all the characters because it is breaking my import into MyPHPAdmin. If they're gone, it all works fine!

Answer (score 3):

Can't you simply select them, then copy and paste into the find/replace dialog?

In any case, you shouldn't see any strange characters in a real UTF8 file when viewing it in UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that but when I do it refuses to paste into the find/replace dialog.

The problem is I do see these weird characters and they are breaking my import whether or not the editor sees them. If you have suggestions on viewing them differently, I'm open to that. I do not see them in ANSCII encoding.